# Access array inside an array - JSON

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

How can I access the array within an array which is a json. "

```
[
  {"series":[
             {"name":"Financial","data":[0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]}, 
             {"name":"Burial","data":[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
             {"name":"Medical","data":[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
            ]
  }
]
```

what i want to access is the array of `"series"` which is

```
[
 {"name":"Financial","data":[0,0,3,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]}, 
 {"name":"Burial","data":[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
 {"name":"Medical","data":[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
]
```

How can I so that in jquery? This is my code

```
series1 = JSON.stringify(data[0]);
alert(series1);
```

what i've got above is the curly brace started from the `"series"` upto the last curly brace. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

both of these will work :

```
data[0].series
or
data[0]['series']
```

and for inside the series :

```
data[0].series[0].name
data[0].series[1].name
```